# Power BI can't select column in NETWORKDAYS()

Tags: powerbi

[image: Power BI Screenshot]

Hi, I have a table with column for first date and last date. I want to know the Turn Around Time between them so I use NETWORKDAYS(). But, I cannot select the date in my columns. Can someone please enlighten me why is this not working? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/networkdays-dax

NETWORKDAYS() doesn't accept columns, but single dates. To use this function you would need a **row context**. So you can either use NETWORKDAYS()

- in a **calculated column**, which results in numbers for every row
- or in an iterator function like SUMX(), which potentially also aggregates the numbers, depending on the filter context.

You are trying to use NETWORKDAYS() directly in a measure, which doesn't work.